# Access2010 error when running: alter table S alter column AGE SMALLINT;

Tags: sql, ms-access

I only use 'Create' to create a table named 'S'.And 'AGE' is one of its columns.The data type of 'AGE' is INT.

```
create table S(SNO char(12),SNAME varchar(10),AGE int,SEX char(1),SDEPT varchar(255),primary key(SNO));
```

When running the following code, appearing messagebox:'Object is invalid or no longer set'.
I am new to Access.Please tell me how to fix it.Thanks!

```
alter table S alter column AGE SMALLINT;
```

Comment: What can we do without your code?

Comment: This runs flawlessly in Access 365. I don't have Access 2010 though. However, your error indicates that the table couldn't be found.